# Getting error while creating button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create button dynamically through angular, i am doing this with JavaScript right now and able to create button, i am trying to change the classname of the button but getting below error ,

error:

> Property 'className' does not exist on type `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>`.

code:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("btnshow")
element.innerHTML = "btnhide";
console.log(HTMLElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You cannot access element.innerHTML like that, you need to access it by index like `element[0].innerHTML` for example.

Comment: thanks for the answer .. its working 
element[0].className= "btnhide";

Answer (score 0):

@jebprubio document.getElementByClassName() return HTMLCOllection of found elements.

In case you are sure, there will be a single element, below code will work:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("btnshow");
element.innerHTML[0].innerHTML = "btnhide";
```

Kindly revert in case there is anything I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting exact code which you have tried, but as you said you are trying to create dynamic button using Angular. As reusable components is a beauty of Angular, you could try making a reusable component.

Please see the following:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmfpht